# Python GUI and TKinter Grid

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to write a program that displays an 8x8 grid. The vertical lines are supposed to be red and the horizontal lines are supposed to be blue. But I can't seem to figure it out. I know it must be in a loop, but I'm not sure even where to start. Please help!

Here's my code so far:

from tkinter import *

```
class Canvas:
def __init__(self):
    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title("Grid")

    self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 200, height = 200,
                         bg = "white")
    self.canvas.pack()

def drawGrid(self):
    self.canvas.create_line()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_line-method for details about the `create_line()` method.

You need two arguments: the coordinates of the line and a fill color. The coordinates are a list of `[x0, y0, x1, y1]`, and they correspond to pixel values with an origin at the top-left corner of the parent widget, so to draw a horizontal green line on your 200x200 `Canvas`, you'd write:

```
self.canvas.create_line(0,0,200,200, fill='green')
```

To create a grid of lines, a for or while loop would work, which modified the list of coordinates at every iteration and passed it to a new `create_line()` function at the end of each loop.

That should get you started.

Comment: For some reason when I type self.canvas.create_line(0,0,200,200, fill = "blue", tags = "line") it doesn't draw it on the canvas. What am I doing wrong?